# Javascript object recursion to find an item at the deepest level

Tags: javascript, object, search, recursion

I'm trying to recursively search an object that contains strings, arrays, and other objects to find an item (match a value) at the deepest level however I'm always getting undefined as the return result.  I can see through some console logging that I am finding the item but it gets overwritten.  Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
  var theCobWeb = {
    biggestWeb: {
      item: "comb",
      biggerWeb: {
        items: ["glasses", "paperclip", "bubblegum"],
        smallerWeb: {
          item: "toothbrush",
          tinyWeb: {
            items: ["toenails", "lint", "wrapper", "homework"]
          }
        }
      },
      otherBigWeb: {
        item: "headphones"
      }
    }
  };

  function findItem (item, obj) {
  var foundItem;
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] === item) {
      foundItem = obj;
    } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].includes(item)) {
      foundItem = obj;
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      findItem(item, obj[key]);
    } 
  }
      return foundItem;
}

var foundIt = findItem('glasses', theCobWeb);
console.log('The item is here: ' + foundIt); // The item is here: undefined
```

Edit: cleaned up the code a bit based on feedback below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function findItem (item, obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] === item) { // if the item is a property of the object
      return obj;            // return the object and stop further searching
    } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].includes(item)) { // if the item is inside an array property of the object
      return obj;            // return the object and stop the search
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) { // if the property is another object
      var res = findItem(item, obj[key]); // get the result of the search in that sub object
      if(res) return res; // return the result if the search was successful, otherwise don't return and move on to the next property
    } 
  }
  return null; // return null or any default value you want if the search is unsuccessful (must be falsy to work)
}
```

**Note 1:** `Array.isArray` and `Array.prototype.includes` already returning booleans so there is no need to check them against booleans.

**Note 2:** You can flip the value of a boolean using the **NOT operator** (`!`).

**Note3:** You have to return the result (if found) immediately after it is found so you won't waste time looking for something you already have.

**Note4:** The return result of the search will be an object (if found) and since objects are passed by reference not by value, changing the properties of that object will change the properties of the original object too.

**Edit:** Find the deepest object:

If you want to find the deepest object, you'll have to go throug every object and sub-object in the object `obj` and everytime you have to store the object and it's depth (if the depth of the result is bigger than the previous result of course). Here is the code with some comments (I used an internal function `_find` that actually get called on all the objects):

```
function findItem (item, obj) {
    var found = null;              // the result (initialized to the default return value null)
    var depth = -1;                // the depth of the current found element (initialized to -1 so any found element could beat this one) (matched elements will not be assigned to found unless they are deeper than this depth)

    function _find(obj, d) {       // a function that take an object (obj) and on which depth it is (d)
        for (var key in obj) {     // for each ...
            // first call _find on sub-objects (pass a depth of d + 1 as we are going to a one deep bellow)
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) { 
                _find(obj[key], d + 1);
            }
            // then check if this object actually contain the item (we still at the depth d)
            else if (obj[key] === item || (Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].includes(item))) {
                // if we found something and the depth of this object is deeper than the previously found element
                if(d > depth) {
                    depth = d;     // then assign the new depth
                    found = obj;   // and assign the new result
                }
            }
        }
    }
    _find(obj, 0);                 // start the party by calling _find on the object obj passed to findItem with a depth of 0

    // at this point found is either the initial value (null) means nothing is found or it is an object (the deepest one)
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  You included some really useful notes on how to cleanup my code.  This doesn't completely accomplish what I'm looking for though.  My goal is to find the item at the deepest level, not the first instance.  So in this example if glasses existed in tinyWeb.items too I would want that returned, not biggerWeb.

Comment: @Phil this seems a little bit tricky as What if there is `"glasses"` in two nested objects but not the at the same depth, should the function return any of them or just the deep one?

Comment: just trying to return the match from the deepest level.  That's why I was trying to recurse the whole object and overwrite `foundItem` on each find.

Comment: @Phil sorry for the late response! Check the **EDIT** section above!

Comment: are we really still writing `for-in` loops? *really*?

Comment: @naomik Is it deprecated? **NO**!

Comment: `criticalThinking.replaceAllWith(EWONTFIX & EDEPRECATED)`

Answer (score 2):

> *"I'm trying to recursively search an object that contains strings, arrays, and other objects to find an item (match a value) at the deepest level however I'm always getting undefined as the return result."*
>
> ```
> var foundIt = findItem('glasses', theCobWeb);
> console.log('The item is here: ' + foundIt); // The item is here: undefined
> ```
>
> *"The item is here ..."* – where?

Well what exactly do you want as a return value? Should it just say `"glasses"` when it's all done? In my opinion, that's kind of pointless – fundamentally it's no better than just returning `true` or `false`.

I wrote this function a while ago because I needed to search a heap of data but also know specifically where it matched. I'd probably revise this a little bit now (or at least include type annotations), but it works as-is, so here you go.

```js
// helpers
const keys = Object.keys
const isObject = x=> Object(x) === x
const isArray = Array.isArray
const rest = ([x,...xs])=> xs

// findDeep
const findDeep = (f,x) => {
  let make = (x,ks)=> ({node: x, keys: ks || keys(x)})
  let processNode = (parents, path, {node, keys:[k,...ks]})=> {
    if (k === undefined)
      return loop(parents, rest(path))
    else if (isArray(node[k]) || isObject(node[k]))
      return loop([make(node[k]), make(node, ks), ...parents], [k, ...path])
    else if (f(node[k], k))
      return {parents, path: [k,...path], node}
    else
      return loop([{node, keys: ks}, ...parents], path)
  }
  let loop = ([node,...parents], path) => {
    if (node === undefined)
      return {parents: [], path: [], node: undefined}
    else
      return processNode(parents, path, node)
  }
  return loop([make(x)], [])
}

// your sample data
var theCobWeb = {biggestWeb: {item: "comb",biggerWeb: {items: ["glasses", "paperclip", "bubblegum"],smallerWeb: {item: "toothbrush",tinyWeb: {items: ["toenails", "lint", "wrapper", "homework"]}}},otherBigWeb: {item: "headphones"}}};

// find path returns {parents, path, node}
let {path, node} = findDeep((value,key)=> value === "glasses", theCobWeb)

// path to get to the item, note it is in reverse order
console.log(path) // => [0, 'items', 'biggerWeb', 'biggestWeb']

// entire matched node
console.log(node) // => ['glasses', 'paperclip', 'bubblegum']
```

The basic intuition here is `node[path[0]] === searchTerm`

---

**Complete path to the matched query**

We get the entire key path to the matched data. This is useful because we know exactly where it is based on the root of our search. To verify the path is correct, see this example

```
const lookup = ([p,...path], x) =>
  (p === undefined) ? x : lookup(path,x)[p]
lookup([0, 'items', 'biggerWeb', 'biggestWeb'], theCobWeb) // => 'glasses'
```

---

**Unmatched query**

Note if we search for something that is not found, `node` will be `undefined`

```
let {path, node} = findDeep((value,key)=> value === "sonic the hog", theCobWeb)
console.log(path) // => []
console.log(node) // => undefined
```

---

**Searching for a specific key/value pair**

The search function receives a `value` and `key` argument. Use them as you wish

```
let {path, node} = findDeep((value,key)=> key === 'item' && value === 'toothbrush', theCobWeb)
console.log(path) // => [ 'item', 'smallerWeb', 'biggerWeb', 'biggestWeb' ]
console.log(node) // => { item: 'toothbrush', tinyWeb: { items: [ 'toenails', 'lint', 'wrapper', 'homework' ] } }
```

---

**Short circuit – 150cc**

Oh and because I spoil you, `findDeep` will give an early return as soon as the first match is found. It won't waste computation cycles and continue iterating through your pile of data after it knows the answer. This is a good thing.

---

**Go exploring**

Have courage, be adventurous. The `findDeep` function above also gives a `parents` property on returned object. It's probably useful to you in some ways, but it's a little more complicated to explain and not really critical for answering the question. For the sake of keeping this answer simplified, I'll just mention it's there.

Comment: tfw when you write a corecursive procedure that's not a toy

Comment: It actually returns the object reference. So not as useless as you seem to think. Thanks for including the other code though, it's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the recursive call doesn't assign the return to the variable.
And you should check the return from the recursive call and return if true or break from the for loop if you have other logic after it.

```
 function findItem(item, obj) {
 for (var key in obj) {
     if (obj[key] === item) {
         return obj;
     } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) === true && obj[key].includes(item) === true) {
         return obj;
     } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && Array.isArray(obj[key]) === false) {
         var foundItem = findItem(item, obj[key]);
         if(foundItem) 
          return foundItem;
     }
 }
```

Comment: that wont work if you look for `headphones` - the `return findItem` should be conditional

Comment: something like - `foundItem = findItem(item, obj[key]);
            if (foundItem) {
                return foundItem;
            }`

Comment: That's true, I've updated it to work for it too , (y)